# How to check if object is castable?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, arduino, esp32

I have following classes:

```
class ATemperatureDevice{};
class AHumidityDevice{};

class BluetoothLeDevice{};

class Sensor1 : BluetoothLeDevice, ATemperatureDevice, AHumidityDevice {};
class Sensor2 : BluetoothLeDevice, AHumidityDevice  {};
```

I have a `vector<BluetoothLeDevice*>`, where all devices are stored.

The Classes ATemperatureDevice, AHumidityDevice and BluetoothLeDevice have virtual functions.

When I pick one, I have a BluetoothLeDevice. Now I want to check if it derives from ATemperatureDevice and/or AHumidityDevice.

I tried dynamic_cast, when its not castable, I should get null but, it says "'dynamic_cast' not permitted with -fno-rtti" although they have virtual functions.

What's the best way to check and cast?

Comment: do you use the `-fno-rtti` compiler flag?

Comment: btw a `vector<BluetoothLeDevice>` cannot hold objects of subclasses of `BluetoothLeDevice` it can only hold objects of type `BluetoothLeDevice`

Comment: You can't have polymorphism with plain objects. Your vector will only store `BluetoothLeDevice` objects, leading to *object slicing* if you attempt to add e.g. a `Sensor1` object. For polymorphism to work you need references or *pointers*.

Comment: After you square away the abovementioned issues with object slicing: the correct way to do this is with virtual functions. Whatever reason you think you need explicit casting: it is wrong. This is what virtual functions are for.

Comment: Your design seems a little flawed by the way. I recommend that you have a *single device* containing *multiple sensors*. Each sensor can only be of a single type (temperature, humidity, etc.). All sensors have a common `BaseSensor` class which defines the interface to read the sensor value. Then e.g. `TemperatureSensor` implements the `BaseSensor` interface. And then your `BluetoothLeDevice` have a vector of pointers to `BaseSensor` for all the sensors of the device.

Comment: As your compiler error is telling you: remove the `-fno-rtti` flag! "RTTI" stands for Run Time Type Information, which is required for `dynamic_cast` to work (info is added to objects, when created, which act as 'class signatures').

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake, of course the vector holds BluetoothLeDevice*

Answer (score 2):

As people already commented, storing polymorphic objects `T` inside a `std::vector<T>` will cause object slicing. Your code makes sense in C#, but in C++ people tend to use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) whenever possible to avoid such issues. In your case this could look like: https://godbolt.org/z/xna1vjnWh

Answer (score 1):

If `dynamic_cast` is not permitted, then store tag to identify derived class.

```
//  Test sample
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class BluetoothLeDevice
{
public:
    enum class DerivedClassMetaInfo
    {
        Sensor1Tag,
        Sensor2Tag
    };

    virtual ~BluetoothLeDevice()
    {
    }



    virtual DerivedClassMetaInfo tag(void) const = 0;

    template <typename TargetType>
    TargetType& to()
    {
        if (TargetType::static_tag != tag())
            throw "Convertion failed";
        return static_cast<TargetType&>(*this);
    }
};

class Sensor1 : public BluetoothLeDevice
{
public:
    static const BluetoothLeDevice::DerivedClassMetaInfo static_tag = BluetoothLeDevice::DerivedClassMetaInfo::Sensor1Tag;
    void show()
    {
        cout << "Sensor1 message" << endl;
    }
    virtual DerivedClassMetaInfo tag(void) const override
    {
        return static_tag;
    }
};


int main()
{
    BluetoothLeDevice* temp = new Sensor1();

    Sensor1& sens = temp->to<Sensor1>();
    sens.show();
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: use this code with cautions, because it does not handle tricky inheritance trees. However you can easy (I guess) improve it